# If $\prod X_{\alpha}$ is locally compact $\Rightarrow$ each...

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, locally-compact-groups

If $X:= \prod X_\alpha$ is locally compact $\Rightarrow$ each $X_\alpha$ is locally compact and $X_\alpha$ is compact for all but finitely many values of $\alpha$

**My solution** So I will use that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is open, continuous map and we know that $X$ is locally compact then $Y$ is locally compact.

Define projection functions $p_\alpha : X \rightarrow X_{\alpha}$, since each $p_i$ is an open continuous map $\Rightarrow$ each $X_\alpha$ is as well locally compact.

For the second part of the proof I will again use projection functions. So we know that since the product is locally compact, for each point $x \in \prod X_\alpha$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of that point there exists compact subspace $C$ of the product such that $x \in U \in C$.And $C$ has all but finitely many projections equal to the whole corresponding space.

Since projections are continuous this spaces must be compact.

Is my proof correct or it is not enough?

Comment: There's a small rectifiable error in your second part. You start with an arbitrary open neighbourhood of your point and say that there is a compact set containing that neighbourhood. You can't say this. You may however, say that there is a compact set containing an open neighbourhood of the point. Your argument can stay pretty much the same after that.

Answer (score 0):

Projections are onto, continuous and open, so it is immediate then that $X_\alpha$ is locally compact $\forall \alpha$. To prove the second part, let $x \in \prod X_\alpha$ and let $U$ be a **compact neighborhood** of $x$. Then $U$ contains a basic neighborhood of the form:

$$p_{\alpha_1}^{-1}(U_{\alpha_1})\cap p_{\alpha_2}^{-1}(U_{\alpha_2})\cap \dots\cap p_{\alpha_n}^{-1}(U_{\alpha_n})$$

Because $\prod X_\alpha$ is indeed equipped with the product topology, and it follows that $p_{\alpha}(U) = X_\alpha \ , \ \forall \alpha \not\in \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$. Since the continuous images of compact subsets are also compact, each $X_\alpha$ is compact at least $\forall \alpha \not\in \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$

Comment: Why do you assume that such *a basic neighborhood* is compact?

Comment: I ain't supposing that.

Comment: Maybe I've not understood your answer, could you explain your second part's solution?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am only supposing that $U$ is compact. What comes after that assumptuion are consequences of working with the product topology.

Comment: @JohnMars  By the way,  I found this argument being used in Stephen Willard's General Topology book, but I don't remember it having more details than my argument.